# Conditional order for nested model based on field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have an Event model which has_many Results. I want to order the results based on a field in Event.

I currently have in Event:

```
  has_many :results, :dependent => :destroy, :include => [:event], 
    :order   => "IF(self.etype = 'Stroke', 'results.score ASC', 'results.score DESC')"
```

...but this deosn't work. Is there a better way to do this with named_scope for example?
Sorry for my stupidy, I am new to Rails.

Comment: Why are you doing `self.etype` in your query?

Comment: I want a different order for all results depending on the `etype` in `Event`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
has_many :results, :dependent => :destroy, :include => [:event], 
  :order   => '#{(self.etype == "Stroke") ? 
                  "results.score ASC" : "results.score DESC"}'
```

When a quoted string OR a plain ruby code is used as an attribute value, it gets evaluated at the class loading time. In such a case,  the `self` is a `class` rather than a instance of a `class`. Since the user wants to change the `ORDER BY` direction based on the value of an attribute on the object in hand condition should be enclosed in side single quote. In such cases the `self` is an instance of the `class`.

Comment: Why even bother with the string? `(self.etype == "Stroke") ? "results.score ASC" : "results.score DESC"`

Comment: When you use the quoted string OR the plain ruby code, the value gets evaluated at the class loading time. In such a case,  the `self` is a `Class` rather than a instance of a `Class`. Since the user wants to change the `ORDER BY` direction based on the value of an attribute of an instance the condition should be enclosed in side single quote.

Comment: Now I'm getting: "SQLite3::SQLException: unrecognized token: "#": ...". Any ideas?

Comment: Andrew in your case I get "undefined method 'etype'"

Comment: You need the quotes the other way around. Exchange the double quotes for single quote and vice-versa.

Comment: Andrew, I tried what you said and I think I'm getting close. I now have `has_many :results, :dependent => :destroy, :include => [:event], :order => "#{self.etype == 'Stroke' ? 'results.score ASC' : 'results.score DESC'}"` but it returns "undefined method `etype` for #<Class:0x59f72a0>". If I change `self.etype` to `:etype` the query works but its always DESC. Thanks for your help so far.

Answer (score 0):

Does this solve it?

```
has_many :results, :dependent => :destroy, :include => [:event], :order => "IF(results.etype = 'Stroke', 'event.score ASC', 'event.score DESC')"
```

If not, what error is returned when you try to do this in the console:

```
Event.first.results
```

Comment: I didn't even try this at the moment because it does not make sense. `score` is in `Result` and `etype` is in `Event`.

Comment: So you want to order the results based on a field in Results, not Event?  Your question said the opposite.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

in rails 3.0.x:

```
has_many :results, :dependent => :destroy, :include => [:event], 
  :order   => "#{(proxy_owner.etype == 'Stroke') ? 
                  'results.score ASC' : 'results.score DESC'}"
```

In rails 3.x.x:

```
has_many :results, :dependent => :destroy, :include => [:event], 
  :order   => "#{(proxy_association.owner.etype == 'Stroke') ? 
                  'results.score ASC' : 'results.score DESC'}"
```

Hope this helps.